# Can't install ubuntu:

Tags: system-installation

I am can't install ubuntu on my windows xp Dell Inspiron laptop. I keep getting the error message saying I need to look at this file, which I can't locate: C:\docume~1\russla~1\locals~1\temp\wubi-14.04-rev286.log. I have downloaded the relevant files. What can I try next?